Check if a fine-tuned OpenAI model was successfully deleted
I am doing some work with the OpenAI API with Python. I'm working with fine-tuning and I am working on deleting an existing model and starting over again. I want to be able to check if the deletion actually succeeded or failed.
The OpenAI.models.delete() function returns a ModelDeleted object. What should I do with it?

A ModelDeleted object has a boolean deleted attribute which tells you whether the model was deleted.
API reference
Python source code
